# JEDI JVScheduleEvents Usage

Tags: delphi, jedi

Can anyone help me with JEDI JCL jvscheduleevent object?
I have an event that I want to change the date and time when it starts / fire.
The change I want to do according to some user settings, when starting the application.
The event is a mountly type, fire once at a specific day and time.

Thank's for your help!

Comment: What have you tried?  What does your code look like?  What is your code doing and what do you expect it to do?  Post code.

Comment: I have a win service app with an jvscheduleevent.On designtime I added an event, which works only once a month at a set time. What executes this event are some extraction of information from the cash registers. What I want to accomplish is that the user can set himself, at runtime, the day and time at which this event takes place.When starting the service, I read the day and hour settings (
when I want to fire de event) and want to edit (modify) event side settings.

Comment: Over jve.events [0] .schedule can't reach all the variables or I'm not looking for the right place (there are not many options but no documentation exists). At the same time I have problems with the variables of type Ttimestamp and I do not know how to convert a variable from Tdatetime to Ttimestamp.I never work with this type of variables.

Comment: Have a look at the unit ``DateUtils`` from Delphi. It should contain functions for working with ``TDateTime`` and ``TTimeStamp``.